# Nomenclature- what is the name for this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a specific name for the following graph?

[image]

"Acyclic tree" is not unique and "one-dimensional lattice" doesn't sound quite right. Saying "line graph" is, in my opinion, ambiguous.

The reason I ask this is because I need to reference this graph without the use of this picture, or any pictures for that matter.

Comment: I've seen this called the path  of length $n$. I've also seen it called the path of length $n-1$. My impression is that the former name is more comm on than the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a  Path graph / Linear Chain / linear graph : It looks like this :
[image: Path graph]

Details : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph